# Access parent object in method

Tags: php, oop, frameworks, kohana, kohana-3

I have a problem i can't even name properly. Here is the situation.

I'm using php framework (kohana3 but it's not important i think) to write a simple cms with entries and uploads. The relations are:

```
Entries -> has_many -> Uploads
Uploads -> belongs_to -> Entries
```

To display all entries with their uploads, i'm using this code in **view** file:

```
foreach( $entries as $entry ) 
{
     foreach( $entry->upload->find_all() as $uploads ) 
     {
          foreach( $uploads->find_all() as $upload )
          {
               echo $upload->file;
          }
     }
}
```

Now i want to create a method in Entry model called `find_first_upload()` which will return first uploaded element. Here is the future usage of it:

```
foreach( $entries as $entry ) 
{
     echo $entry->find_first_upload()->file;
}
```

and the important thing is that **i don't want to** pass any variables to `find_first_upload()` method like for example `$entry` object or currently looped entry id.
What i want to achieve is to be able to get currently looped entry object inside `find_first_upload` method - it'll allow me to make a foreach's inside of it.

Have you any ideas how can i code that?

If you have any questions, feel free to ask them here.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function find_first_upload() {
    $result = 0;
     foreach( $this->upload->find_all() as $uploads ) 
         {
              foreach( $uploads->find_all() as $upload )
              {
                if(empty($result))
                   $result = $upload;
              }
         }
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: Yeah! That's what i was looking for :) Thanks a lot! However i don't understand one thing. i can display `file` property using `return $upload->file` in model but if i'll write `return $upload` and use `echo $entry->find_first_upload()->file` in **view**, i'm getting `Undefined property: Database_MySQL_Result::$file` error. How is that possible? It's quite important for me to be able to choose properties from a view

Comment: maybe because you are in the upper object i mean parent object and its not that property in it and the file property is fill in the childes

Comment: if the ansewer is corect please tick the answer and klick the uper arrow for my answer ;)

Comment: Don't worry i'll tick answer for sure! I just wan't to fix this one small issue. Have you any idea on how to make that? I'm asking because this solution is worthless for me until i can't get custom fields from a view

Comment: you can return just the $upload not $upload->file

Comment: when i'm doing this, i'm getting this property error mentioned in first comment

Comment: i am thinking but i have nothing to say if you find any answer commented to me

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for reviving this old topic, but I was googling something and stumbled on this. In case anyone has a similar issue, ignore the accepted answer, this is the correct way:

```
public function find_first_upload()
{
    return $this->uploads->find();
}
```